# What are the fonts that support greek language?

Tags: fonts, languages, greek, font-encodings

I am typing a document which uses both english and greek language.However when I attempt to change the font of my document In the case of many fonts that I have tried the change affects only english characters leaving the greek ones in the default latex font.So I wonder is this problem caused by the fact that these fonts are not supported in greek or is there any other mistake that I do and I ignore? If the problem is the lack of support how can I find which fonts support greek language? By the way this problem is not general.In fact some fonts when applied act as expected changing both the greek and english characters .Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should show what you did, in pdflatex you need `\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}` ecoding and `\usepackage[greek]{babel}` to set up Greek. I lualatex or xelatex most opentype fonts should support Greek

Comment: `fc-list :lang=el`

Comment: As far as I know, at least`CM Unicode` and `erewhon` support Greek  language.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why is \usepackage[LGR]{fontenc} important for typing Greek? I mean I am typing in Greek without using it and I have no problem at least with the default latex font. Is there any case that my problem can be attributed to not using it?